# Python / Regular Expression Token conversion with parameter capture

Tags: python, regex

I have a string in the form of:

`"Hello, this is a test.  Let's tag @[William Maness], and then tag @[Another name], along with @[More Name]."`

I want to convert that to...

`"Hello, this is a test. Let's tag <a href='/search/william-maness'>William Maness</a>, and then tag <a href='/search/another-name'>Another name</a>, along with [...]"`

I'm fairly sure this can be done with regex, but it's just a bit too complex for me to work out.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`re.sub()` accepts functions as well, so you can process the replacement text:

```
import re

text = "Hello, this is a test. Let's tag @[William Maness], and then tag @[Another name], along with @[More Name]."

def replace(match):
    text = match.group(1)  # Extract the first capturing group

    return '<a href="/search/{0}">{1}</a>'.format(  # Format it into a link
        text.lower().replace(' ', '-'),
        text
    )

re.sub(r'@\[(.*?)\]', replace, text)
```

Or, if you're looking for a readable one-liner:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'@\[(.*?)\]', (lambda m: (lambda x: '<a href="/search/{0}">{1}</a>'.format(x.lower().replace(' ', '-'), x))(m.group(1))), text)
'Hello, this is a test. Let\'s tag <a href="/search/william-maness">William Maness</a>, and then tag <a href="/search/another-name">Another name</a>, along with <a href="/search/more-name">More Name</a>.'
```

Comment: That is epic!  Thanks Blender.  That is EXACTLY what I needed.  Elapsed time, 4 minutes.  I bow to you in your regexp awesomeness.

Answer (score 2):

You can match any such a name with:

```
r'@\[([^]]+)\]'
```

The capturing group surrounds the name inside the brackets in the original text.

You could then use a function passed to `sub()` to substitute the names with links, based on a lookup you have:

```
def replaceReference(match):
    name = match.group(1)
    return '<a href="/search/%s">%s</a>' % (name.lower().replace(' ', '-'), name)

refs = re.compile(r'@\[([^]]+)\]')
refs.sub(replaceReference, example)
```

The function is passed a match object for each match found; the capturing group is retrieved with `.groups(1)`.

In this example the name is transformed in a very simple manner, but you could do actual database checks if the name exists, for example.

Demo:

```
>>> refs.sub(replaceReference, example)
'Hello, this is a test. Let\'s tag <a href="/search/william-maness">William Maness</a>, and then tag <a href="/search/another-name">Another name</a>, along with <a href="/search/more-name">More Name</a>.'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using @Martijn's regex:

```
>>> s
"Hello, this is a test. Let's tag @[William Maness], and then tag @[Another name], along with @[More Name]."
>>> re.sub(r'@\[([^]]+)\]', r'<a href="/search/\1</a>', s)
'Hello, this is a test. Let\'s tag <a href="/search/William Maness</a>, and then tag <a href="/search/Another name</a>, along with <a href="/search/More Name</a>.'
```

You need to slugiy your usernames, though.